Debian 12.8 compatibility issues with Nvidia GeForce RTX 4090
I recently set up my new laptop for dual boot with Debian 12.8 alongside Windows 11. My main reason for doing this is that I need to program in C/C++ and develop in ROOT, and I’d prefer to have a “separate machine” optimized specifically for this purpose. In the past, I primarily used Ubuntu but only for basic tasks like checking emails and writing documents. Motivated by free software philosophy and Debian’s reputation for stability, I decided to give it a try on my new laptop. However, I am facing issues right from the start. The OS installed correctly, but it appears there are compatibility issues with Nvidia GPUs on Linux distros. In particular, I use an external monitor connected via HDMI, but it does not receive any signal when I boot into Debian.
This is my computer:
HP OMEN 17-ck2003ns Intel Core i9-13900HX/32GB/2TB SSD/RTX 4090/17.3"
Any help on resolving this specific issue (the external monitor not displaying anything) would be greatly appreciated. Additionally, I’d love general advice on how to become a more proficient Linux user, especially in regard to package management and system administration.
Please note that I am looking for an optimal solution to fully utilize the power of the RTX 4090. I mention this because I’ve heard that some OS setups, like Ubuntu, may install drivers that ensure compatibility but at the cost of significantly sacrificing the performance of the RTX 4090. I would like to avoid this behavior and instead find the best configuration, as I plan to run heavy simulations
Kind regards
Miguel

Read NVIDIA Optimus

I’ve heard that some OS setups, like Ubuntu, may install drivers that ensure compatibility but at the cost of significantly sacrificing the performance of the RTX 4090 You've heard a bunch of crap then. Performance wise there's absolutely ZERO differences between Debian and Ubuntu considering the same conditions (same Nvidia driver, same DE).
